# Why have we created an instance of abstract class when we are not allowed?

Tags: android, abstract-class, google-api-client

this person has done:"protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;" in the following code :

[Android Maps Get Longitude and Latitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31175427/android-maps-get-longitude-and-latitude)

but GoogleApiClient is an abstract class.

How it's instance can be created ?

Abstract class as mentioned here:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient

Should'nt it be extended as abstract classes can only be extended?

Comment: An abstract class cannot be instantiated directly. The user is not attempting to do that so there is no problem.

Comment: The statement in this message is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not instantiated directly. If you look at the code in the link you provide, this is how an instance of a **subclass** of `GoogleApiClient` is produced :

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
```

We don't use the `new` keyword here, but rather the `build` method from the static class `Builder`